# Where is OpenCV installed?

Tags: opencv

I have followed this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV#Installation) to install OpenCV 2.4.8

OpenCV documentation says that I should find OpencV `usr/local/include/opencv/` yet I find nothing.

Can someone tell me where to find the installed OpenCV files?

---

**EDIT** 
I'm not sure why the script installed OpenCV 2.4.8 instead of 2.4.9.

But I just found the files here here `/usr/include/opencv` and `/usr/include/opencv2` 
I am not sure how that works but it does.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, the OpenCV4 is located under `/usr/include/opencv4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV is installed via `checkinstall`, have a look at the installer script.

Therefore you can check the installed files via

```
dpkg -L opencv-<version>
```

Eg:

```
dpkg -L opencv-2.4.8
```

---

If you have installed OpenCV via another script as you commented, open the script, find the line

```
make install
```

and replace with

```
sudo checkinstall
```

After that install `checkinstall` via

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Now start the installer script again and check the installed files with

```
dpkg -L opencv
```

The installer script does exactly the same as before, but now it creates and installs a deb package.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I installed 2.4.8  with this [script] (https://gist.github.com/smithjessk/bde98ec9297b38bad40c)

But I get this `dpkg-query: package 'opencv-2.4.8' is not installed`

Answer (score 3):

Currently OpenCV 2.4 is provided via

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv
```

(if packages were not resolved try: libopencv* or opencv*)

Using package distribution from the Ubuntu repository may require you to update your indexes and packages (to be able to find actual OpenCV version available):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After apt-get installing OpenCV, the latest available version (2.4.x) will be installed into your default system path:

`/usr/local/lib` - shared libraries (e.g. `/usr/local/lib/libopencv-core2.4.x`)
`/usr/local/include` - header files (e.g. `/usr/local/include/opencv2`)

See [this guide](http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/) (this is not my guide, so I am not aware if it is good or bad)

Comment: To add to this, **$PATH** environment variable should have /usr/local directory. Thus, whenever you compile your app this variable provides the default research directories for the compiler to search throught in order to find necessary dependencies.

Comment: could you write example, please, I have three versions and I need to know their paths.@andrgolubev

Comment: @REDHWAN in theory, you might use "whereis" bash command to figure out the path to binary - https://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis

Answer (score 2):

Generally I follow this pattern:

```
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf`

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Then you can use

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv
```

to get all include and libs on Ubuntu